# Inner DIV color text is not changing on MOUSE HOVER

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**This is my requirement:**

I have *"Ttile"* and *"Description"* .

1. On page Load, "outerElementsContainer"(DIV ID) div background should
   be WHITE
2. "Title" & "Border" Color should be GREEN, "Description color should
   be to BLACK.
3. On mouse hover of "outerElementsContainer"(DIV ID) div, DIV
   background should change to  GREEN
4. "Title" Color should change to WHITE, "Description" color should
   change to WHITE.
5. On mouse out of "outerElementsContainer"(DIV ID) div, DIV background
   should change to  WHITE
6. "Title" & "Border" Color should change to GREEN, "Description" color
   should change to BLACK.

**I am stuck at "Description" color. It is not changing on mouse hover.**

**Below is my HTML code:**

```
 <div id="outerElementsContainer">
 <div id="123456" name="123456"    onMouseOut="this.style.background='WHITE';this.style.color='GREEN';"
onmouseover="this.style.background='GREEN';this.style.color='WHITE';"
style="float:left; margin-right:2em;cursor: pointer;   color:'GREEN';width:18em;height:12em; 
  border-color:'GREEN'; border-width:1px;margin-top: 1em;      border-style:solid;">

                     <div id="InnerDiv1" 
                     style="background-color:'GREEN';height:0.5em;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                     </div>

                     <div id="InnerDiv2"
                     style="height: 3.5em; overflow: hidden;margin-left: 0.5em;font-size: larger;font-weight: bold;">
                         <p id="title">Title</p>
                     </div>

                     <div id="InnerDiv3" 

                     style="height: 5em;overflow: hidden;margin: 0.5em;color:black;">
                         <p id="Description">Description</p>
                     </div>
                 </div>  

             </div>
```

How to solve this??

Comment: Thanks for providing answers. some answers are not helped me , it sorted out of some other things in my requirements. Graham and Jai mostly thanks to you guys. 

Am i worng posting this question as if its a useless question??
Then y I got down point as if i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

use css:

```
#description:hover{
 background-color: green;
color: black;
}
```

this will turn the background color green when your mouse is over the div with an `id` of `123456`, when your mouse isn't over the div the background will return to white.

see - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

to use CSS, either make a .css file and include it in the `<head>` section of your html page like so - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCSSFile.css">` <- is better practice, see - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

if you want to you could also include the CSS styling in your html file, like so in the `<head>` section -

```
<style>
    #description:hover{
     background-color: green;
     color:black;
    }
</style>
```

which isn't as good as making a file for the CSS itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the css property `color:black` :

```
<div id="InnerDiv3" style="height: 5em;overflow: hidden;margin: 0.5em;color:black;">
<p id="Description">Description</p>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="InnerDiv3" style="height: 5em;overflow: hidden;margin: 0.5em;">
<p id="Description">Description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css only:

```css
body{color:black;}

#outerElementsContainer > div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: 'GREEN';
  width: 18em;
  height: 12em;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
#InnerDiv2 {
  height: 3.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#InnerDiv2 p{color:green;}
#InnerDiv3{
height: 5em;overflow: hidden;margin: 0.5em;
}

#outerElementsContainer:hover > div {
  background:green;
  border:green 1px green;
  color:white;
  }

#outerElementsContainer:hover p{
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerElementsContainer">
  <div id="123456" name="123456">

    <div id="InnerDiv1">
    </div>

    <div id="InnerDiv2">
      <p id="title">Title</p>
    </div>

    <div id="InnerDiv3">
      <p id="Description">Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

see in Description  in InnerDiv3  div you are applied inine css color:black and inline css has more priority  thats why color  is not changing.

i have written  you a simplified solution below using jquery with your requirement

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#123456").mouseover(function(e) {
    $(".greenColor").css("background-color", "green");
    $(".blackColor").css("color", "black");
    $(".whiteColor").css("color", "white");
  });
  $("#123456").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(".greenColor").css("background-color", "white");
    $(".blackColor").css("color", "green");
    $(".whiteColor").css("color", "black");
  });
});
```

```css
.greenColor {} .blackColor {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerElementsContainer">
  <div id="123456" name="123456" class="greenColor" style="float:left; margin-right:2em;cursor: pointer;   color:'GREEN';width:18em;height:12em; 
  border-color:GREEN; border-width:1px;margin-top: 1em;border-style:solid;">

    <div id="InnerDiv1" style="height:0.5em;margin-bottom: 10px;">
    </div>

    <div id="InnerDiv2" style="height: 3.5em; overflow: hidden;margin-left: 0.5em;font-size: larger;font-weight: bold;color:Green" class="blackColor">
      <p id="title">Title</p>
    </div>

    <div id="InnerDiv3" style="height: 5em;overflow: hidden;margin: 0.5em;color:black;">
      <p id="Description" class="whiteColor">Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

hope so this will help you lot

Answer (score 0):

try this.I think this is what you want.if this is not the case tell me.I wrote a full code for you.just copy,paste and try it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

div.outerelement{
  width:500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border:1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}


h1.ttl{
  color: green;
}

h1.des{
  color: black;
}

.classOne{
  background-color: green;
}
.classTwo{
  color:white;
}

</style>
<body>

<div class="outerelement">
  <h1 class="ttl">Title</h1>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <h1 class="des">Description</h1>
</div>
  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".outerelement").mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).css({"background-color":"green"},1000);
      $(".ttl").css({"color":"white"},1000);
      $(".des").css({"color":"white"},1000);
    });

     $(".outerelement").mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).css({"background-color":"white"},1000);
      $(".ttl").css({"color":"green"},1000);
      $(".des").css({"color":"black"},1000);
    });

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```